# Environment variables not passed to the user

Tags: debian, environment-variables, variable

Even though I set `ENVIRONMENT=production` in `/etc/environment` and `DefaultEnvironment=ENVIRONMENT=production` in `/etc/systemd/system.conf` the variable `ENVIRONMENT` (which should be global by now) is not passed to the user when I check for it using the `env`/`printenv` command. I also set `Defaults env_keep+="ENVIRONMENT"` in `/etc/sudoers`. What have I done wrong or forgotten?

I'm on Debian and I connect to the server via SSH.

Comment: Have you rebooted or at least logged out before checking?

Comment: @terdon yes, multiple times.

Comment: Only if I run `su - user -c 'env | grep -- ENVIRONMENT'` I see the environment variable, but nowhere else.

Comment: `PAM` wasn't activated in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Now it passes the `PAM` file `/etc/environment`.

Comment: What does ssh have to do with it? Were you sshing into the machine? Could you post your solution as an answer so we can mark this as done?

Comment: @terdon sure, will do

Answer (score 2):

As requested, I will answer my own question, or rather the solution to my problem: `PAM` had been deactivated (`UsePAM no`) in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` which prevented `/etc/environment` (directly related to `PAM`) to be interpreted when connecting to the server over SSH. After enabling PAM in the SSH configuration, I have been able to use the environment variables deposited in the aforementioned file.